# Apache ProxyHTMLURLMap with string substitution from LocationMatch

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to build an Apache reverse proxy to make a set of servers accessible through a single point of access. The servers all offer a web admin interface on port 3000, and I intend to present all of them as directories on the reverse proxy. The interfaces contain local links which must of course be rewritten to go to the correct server's subdirectory on the proxy.

I can achieve the required behaviour with configuration snippets like this for each server individually:

```
<Location /testadmin-warsaw/>
        ProxyPass http://warsaw.example.com:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable  On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  / /testadmin-warsaw/ L
        RequestHeader    unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

As this gets rather tedious and error-prone as servers come and go, I am aiming for a dynamic configuration.
According to the Apache documentation, the following should work:

```
<LocationMatch "^/testadmin-(?<OFFICENAME>\w+)/(.*)$">
        ProxyPassMatch   http://$1.example.com:3000/$2
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable  On
        ProxyHTMLInterp  On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  / /testadmin-${env:MATCH_OFFICENAME|unknown}/ VL
        RequestHeader    unset Accept-Encoding
</LocationMatch>
```

`<LocationMatch>` would set the environment variable `MATCH_OFFICENAME` to the office name part of the directory, and `ProxyHTMLURLMap` would insert this name at the appropriate place in the rewritten links.

But when I test that configuration, a link originally pointing to `/other/page.html` is rewritten to `/testadmin-unknown/other/page.html` instead of `/testadmin-warsaw/other/page.html` as intended. In other words, `ProxyHTMLURLMap` acts as if the environment variable `MATCH_OFFICENAME` was unset.

If I omit the `env:` part and put just `/testadmin-${MATCH_OFFICENAME}/` as the to-pattern, Apache logs a warning: "AH00111: Config variable ${MATCH_OFFICENAME} is not defined".

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Isn't the %-sign used for env vars in apache? ProxyHTMLURLMap  / /testadmin-%{env:MATCH_OFFICENAME}/ VL

Comment: That's what I thought initially, too, but it does not work at all. It produces `/testadmin-%{env:MATCH_OFFICENAME}/other/page.html` literally with no substitution happens at all. According to the [Apache manual entry for ProxyHTMLURLMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlurlmap), you have to use the `$` sign,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax *without* `env:` is correct.
The `AH00111` warning message it produces is spurious, as per [Apache Bug #58467](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58467).

The configuration:

```
<LocationMatch "^/testadmin-(?<OFFICENAME>\w+)/(.*)$">
        ProxyPassMatch   http://$1.example.com:3000/$2
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable  On
        ProxyHTMLInterp  On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  / /testadmin-${MATCH_OFFICENAME|unknown}/ VL
        RequestHeader    unset Accept-Encoding
</LocationMatch>
```

works as intended, except for the spurious warning at each startup.